# Iterator.remove() removes all elements while I want to remove one

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

There are questions on how to remove specific elements from an ArrayList but not an Iterator of an ArrayList. Using the code below, it removes all the elements in the ArrayList, but I want to remove the specific element, the element that collided with the player. Can anyone please tell me how to change this code to make it do so? Thanks in advance.

```
public void update() {
        for(Iterator<Object> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Object o = iter.next();
            o.update();
            if(Enemy.collide == true) {
                iter.remove();
            } 
        }  

    }
```

Here is the object class(enemy and player class extend this):

```
    package game;



public abstract class Object {

    protected float x;
    protected float y;
    protected float sX, sY;

    abstract void update();

    public void render() {
        Draw.Rect(x, y, sX, sY);
    }
    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public float getSX() {
        return sX;
    }
    public float getSY() {
        return sY;
    }
    public float getCenterY() {
        return y + sY/2;
    }
    public void removeObject(Object o) {
        Game.list2.remove(o);
        Game.list = Game.list2;
        Enemy.collide = false;

    }
}
```

Enemy class:

```
    package game;

import java.util.Iterator;



public class Enemy extends Object {

    private int i = 0;
    private int health = 100;
    private int point = 0;

    static boolean collide = false;

    Enemy(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.sX = Player.size;
        this.sY = Player.size;
    }


    void update() { 
        if(Physics.checkCollision(this, Game.player)) {
            collide = true;
        }

        if(Math.abs(Game.player.x - this.x) <= 30 && Math.abs(Game.player.x - this.x) >= 1 && Physics.checkCollision(this, Game.player) != true) {
            switch(i) {
            case 1:

                break;
            case 0: 
                if(Game.player.x >= this.x) this.x++;
                if(Game.player.x <= this.x) this.x--;
                if(Game.player.y >= this.y) this.y++;
                if(Game.player.y <= this.y) this.y--;
                break;
            }

        } 




    }


}
```

Player class:

```
package game;

public class Player extends Object {


    public final static  float size = 30;


    public Player(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.sX = size;
        this.sY = size;
    }
    public void update() {


    }
    public void moveY(double magY) {
        y += magY;
    }
    public void moveX(double magX) {
        x += magX;
    }

}
```

Comment: No, we can't, because we have no idea what `Enemy.collide` is (other than that it's a **single** boolean set outside the context of the code you've given). You need to make `Enemy.collide` something that relates to a specific entry in the list, perhaps a method that you call passing the item into or similar.

Comment: Are you sure <code>Enemy.collide</code> is false for others. It seems to be a static field.

Comment: Your question is meaningless without `Enemy` class code.

Comment: your `Enemy.collide` property seems static and independent on object `o`.

Comment: Wait... `o.update()` ? There is no `update()` function in java `Object` ! Please, **never** call a personal class `Object`. It's confusing and could lead to problematic import.

Comment: Sorry, I will post all the other classes to clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first big issue, please rename your `Object` class in something like `GameObject`. I didn't see any `import game.Object`, and so suppose that your `Enemy` and `Player` class extends from `java.lang.Object`.

Then, `collide` should be a non-static field, to allow a per-instance collision.

```
for(Iterator<Object> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    Object o = iter.next();
    o.update();
    if(o.collide == true) {
        iter.remove();
    } 
}
```

Moreover, you can simply do `collide = Physics.checkCollision(this, Game.player` instead using a `if`. This allows the `collide` boolean to be set on `false` at the end of a collision.

Finally, you should check if `Physics.checkCollision(this, Game.player)` returns the expected result =)

Good luck !

Comment: @Programmer_10111 Well, the `collide` field belongs to `Enemy`, so you can't access it with `o.collide`, because `o` is a `(Game)Object`.  You can move this field into `(Game)Object`, or better, create a `CollideObject` which extends `(Game)Object`, then iterate on the `CollideObject` instead of `(Game)Object`. You can also do an `instanceof Enemy` and cast it, `((Enemy)o).collide`, but it's often a proof of a bad design ;)

Comment: @Programmer_10111 Glad to be helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Some WTFs which i noticed:

1. `public abstract class Object` - seriously?! Dont name your own classes like classes from `java.lang` or other classes from standard library.
2. `static boolean collide = false;` ofc your iterator goes through your list and remove all of them. Only those fields should be static which are independent from concrete instances. Possibly actual problem is different but i strongly recommend to change design of that part.
3. `float` has bad accuracy when you're dealing with graphics. It should cause many rounding errors.
4. `Physics.checkCollision(this, Game.player)` show this code, and i also recommend to move this code to `Object` and use proper design pattern to handle different cases of objects which are really collided.